# str_replace has no effect on my string

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a problem with str_replace, my function has no effect, i suppose it's due to invisible character but i don't know why...
I want to replace 2 tags  by only one.
Thanks

```
<?php
    $tempo = str_replace( '  </Ligne>
     </Ligne>', '  </Ligne>', $temp);
?>
```

My text file

```
<Ligne>
  <Ligne>
   <ll>test</ll>
   <Id>23</Id>
   <SKU>autreID</SKU>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Ligne>
  <Ligne>
   <ll>test</ll>
   <Id>23</Id>
   <SKU>autreID</SKU>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Ligne>
 </Ligne>
```

Comment: the above code is unclear. What's in `$search` ?

Comment: yes sorry , updated...

Comment: Is this PHP?  You need to tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: yes it's php , i added the tag

Comment: Can't tell if you missed <?php ?> or if this is 2 separate pieces of code.

Comment: sorry i updated again, hope it's clear

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear whether the whitespaces in your text file are the same as the ones in your call to `str_replace`. It might be easier using `preg_replace` instead and checking for any type of whitespace. Something like this:

```
<?php
    $string = '     </Ligne>         </Ligne>';
    $pattern = '/<\/Ligne>\w+<\/Ligne>/';
    $replacement = '</Ligne>';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```